# How to format string passed to Pool::new of mysql crate in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do the beginning of the basic example of [the `mysql` crate's documentation](https://docs.rs/mysql/latest/mysql/), but with a formatted string instead of one that is completely hard-coded:

```rust
use mysql::*;
use std::error::Error;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    // These will be read from a config file
    let user = "root";
    let pw = "password";
    let host = "localhost";
    let port = 3307;
    let db = "db_name";

    let url = format!("mysql://{user}:{pw}@{host}:{port}/{db}");
    let pool = Pool::new(url)?; // Error at this line
    let mut conn = pool.get_conn()?;
    
    Ok(())
}
```

However I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Opts: From<std::string::String>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:13:23
    |
13  |     let pool = Pool::new(url)?;
    |                --------- ^^^ the trait `From<std::string::String>` is not implemented for `Opts`
    |                |
    |                required by a bound introduced by this call
```

I'm new to Rust and searched for a solution all evening. Why is the output of `format!` not implementing `From<String>`? How can I pass a formatted string to `Pool::new` instead of a hard-coded one? Thanks

Comment: Can you try with `Pool::new(url.as_str())?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd build an [`OptsBuilder`](https://docs.rs/mysql/latest/mysql/struct.OptsBuilder.html) instead of a connection string:

```rust
use mysql::*;
use std::error::Error;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    // These will be read from a config file
    let user = "root";
    let pw = "password";
    let host = "localhost";
    let port = 3307;
    let db = "db_name";
    let opts = OptsBuilder::new()
        .user(Some(user))
        .pass(Some(pw))
        .ip_or_hostname(Some(host))
        .tcp_port(port)
        .db_name(Some(db));
    let pool = Pool::new(opts)?;
    let mut conn = pool.get_conn()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

but if you really want to, you can just convert the `String` that `format!` produces into a `&str`, since there are generics involved the easiest way is to use `.as_str()`:

```rust
    let url = format!("mysql://{user}:{pw}@{host}:{port}/{db}");
    let pool = Pool::new(url.as_str())?;
```

Comment: I tried with `.to_string()`, didn't think about `.as_str()`... But I think I prefer the OptsBuilder solution. Thank you!